# emacs error: "Symbol's value as variable is void: hostname"

Tags: emacs, hostname

After I installed emacs this error occurs every time on startup. It prevents me from installing plugins, e.g. auctex via aptitude. I already tried to install a plugin by hand (rails for ruby), but doesn't work.

The error doesn't contain the message "hostname", but the hostname of my PC is displayed ("bloodredangel-ubuntu"). I changed my hostname to "bloodredangel", but the error message stays the same. While I changed my hostname I saw that in /etc/hostname were two entries:

```
127.0.0.1
bloodredangel-ubuntu
```

I already asked this question in an ubuntu forum but they couldn't help. They recognised an misconfigured /etc/hosts file, which I corrected, but from time to time these incorrect configurations get attached by something. I didn't add them by hand, maybe it has something to do with the issue. The misconfigurations looked like this:

```
127.0.0.1             127.0.0.1
bloodredangel-ubuntu  localhost.localdomain  localhost
127.0.0.1             127.0.0.1:8080
bloodredangel-ubuntu  localhost.localdomain  localhost
```

I didn't found a solution on the internet, so I hope I will find help here finally.

Comment: you can try running emacs with the --debug-init option, which will hopefully give you a more meaningful stack trace

Comment: this question should be migrated to Emacs Stack Exchange

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"Solved" it by reinstalling Ubuntu. Was less work than expected. (Backupped the home folder, so reinstalling took approximately 4h with making an backup and playing it back.)

Answer (score 0):

Try adding `(setq hostname "bloodredangel")` (or whatever other hostname you want to set it as) to the beginning of your .emacs file.